# linux based android repo build boringssl libcrypto-host undefined reference to `sha512_block_data_order'

Tags: android-source, undefined-reference, boringssl

while compiling android firmware on linux Ubuntu 16.04 x86-64 host

```
uname -sm
Linux x86_64
```

following error occur in boringssl module:

```
out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcrypto-host_intermediates/src/crypto/sha/sha512.o: 
In function `SHA512_Transform':
/media/compilation/projects/android/beagle2/external/boringssl/src/crypto/sha/sha512.c:184: 
undefined reference to `sha512_block_data_order'
```

and there is a long list of other symbols missing specifically for libcrypto-host module.

tried and solved by removing linux platform escape in "external/boringssl/Android.mk"

was:

```
ifneq ($(HOST_OS),linux)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM
endif
```

now just:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM
```

please confirm if it's the correct approach or there is another way to fix missing flag application?

Comment: Your `HOST_OS` gets set by the following code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/737bc02ee8d38069e72fd86e60c79abdca590b4e/core/envsetup.mk#44. Is `uname -sm` on your machine returning something different?

Comment: "uname -sm" returns:
Linux x86_64

Comment: This might be helpful about the implications: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9440